stuck at grub. cant repair boot - LUKS encryption
this is my first time installing a linux system. I wanted to use Kubuntu and also use LUKS Encryption.
I used this guide to install KUbuntu including LUKS Encryption:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019
It seemed like everything worked fine, but after the whole installation and rebooting the PC I get stuck at the grub screen.
I cant boot, because I cant initialize the kernel. I checked out many posts, which basically told me to do as this post
Stuck at GRUB command line
I tried the boot-repair using the live session on my usb stick, but all I got is this information: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6J3YKDTdpN/
I tried to boot into all other boot options on my pc but it didnt work out, always the same results => GRUB
Can somebody help me out with this?
Thank you in forward!
